# Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance

Tags: next.js

When making a build for production, I keep getting this error. I never had the issue before upgrading to version 12.0.0.
I tried deleting the file, but it only works when the dev server is not running, while it runs I cannot open or delete it and that make every production build fail.

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build .events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\etc\ss\ss\ss\.next\trace'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at D:\etc\ss\ss\ss\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:287421
    at D:\etc\ss\ss\ss\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:287860
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:164:23) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\etc\\ss\\ss\\ss\\.next\\trace'
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just stop `npm run dev` then run `npm run build`. That worked for me.

Comment: But why this happens is there any bug in next.js ?